# ViewPager in Relativelayout and scrollview , how it should be placed?

Tags: android

I have the below XML , text views buttons and images that slides on touch.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

   <TextView android:id="@+id/nameview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#FFFFE0"
       android:paddingBottom="10dp"
       android:paddingTop="14dp"
       android:paddingLeft="45dp"
       android:fontFamily="Arial"
       android:textSize="18sp"
       android:textStyle="bold" />


 <ImageView android:id="@+id/SingleView" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/nameview"/>

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/funnyBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SingleView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/funnyBtn" />


   <Button
        android:id="@+id/CommentBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SingleView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ShareBtn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/funnyBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/CommentBtn" />

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/ShareBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SingleView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/funnyBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@share/ShareBtn" />

   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ShareBtn"
    android:background="#ff00ff00" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:padding="10dip" >

       <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#ffffff" />

            </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>


     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

When I run this xml , it s giving me wrong results .. I guess problem from ViewPager its placed wrong , if I add the viewpager inside scroll view i have the below error
scroll view can host only one direct child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add ViewPager in ScrollView , add it inside LinearLayout , since " scroll view can host only one direct child" .

```
   <ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_below="@+id/ShareBtn"
   android:background="#ff00ff00" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:padding="10dip" >

   <View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"       
        android:background="#ffffff" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  

        </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```